# Does MonoGame 3.3 still have content template projects

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, project-template

I am getting started with using MonoGame and having downloaded version 3.3 in the process of getting my first game setup I've hit an immediate roadblock.

In all the tutorials I have seen such as http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-managing-content it appears that I should be able to find a project template titled 'MonoGame Content Project' in Visual Studio which I can use to add my models and textures. However I do not have such an option in my template list which looks as follows.

[image]

Under XNA Game studio I do appear to have an option for a 'Empty Content Project' but my assumption is that this is not the same thing.

Could anyone provide any guidance? Has my install stuffed up somehow or has the content creation process for MonoGame been changed since this tutorial (and the others I have read) been written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up working this out myself.

Basically that project template type is no longer required and the functionality appears to be have been moved to the MonoGame Pipeline Tool.

All your models and textures can be added and managed through the tool.

Complete details can be viewed [here](http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=Using_The_Pipeline_Tool).